# Cannot insert datetime with mysql command line

Tags: mysql

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)
>
> ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
>
> Do not perform full checking of dates. Check only that the month is in
>   the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31. This
>   is very convenient for Web applications where you obtain year, month,
>   and day in three different fields and you want to store exactly what
>   the user inserted (without date validation). This mode applies to DATE
>   and DATETIME columns. It does not apply TIMESTAMP columns, which
>   always require a valid date.
>   (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

If I type

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datetime%format';

it says: %y- %m- %d %H: %i: %s

I tried to insert 1999-04-26 13:00:00 and says wrong syntax.

I tried to add to the table *ALLOW_INVALID_DATES* after declaring the DATETIME, then tried at the end of the table creation and error.

I'm puzzled...

Thank you for your time

Comment: If it's saying "wrong syntax" then maybe the problem wasn't with the date format, but with your SQL. Please show a full session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE abc ( daterow DATETIME);

INSERT INTO abc(daterow) VALUES('1999-04-26 13:00:00');
```

Comment: Great! I know now why :s. Thank you! Works:)